# Two Rails applications under the same domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've developed a website using RefineryCMS, and now the client have asked for a forum, so I've downloaded [altered_beast](https://github.com/stiff/altered_beast). Now, I want to deploy both of them under the same domain name, so the forum will be at domain.com/forum.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this the best option that worked for me: http://www.site5.com/support/kb/how-to-deploy-a-rails-3-x-application-with-phusion-passenger/

Answer (score 2):

What webserver are you using (if any)? If you're using Apache/Nginx/Lighttpd as a proxy or server with Passenger or whatsoever, you can easily 'mount' another app on a subdirectory.

In the case of Apache you can do so by specifying a `<Location /forum> proxy/passenger calls here </Location>` block, with Nginx using `location /forum { proxy/passenger call here }` and with Lighttpd or any other web server really probably in a similar way.

Comment: I'm using Apache and Passenger. Almost sure

Comment: Alright, well, if you modify the configuration of your main site's vhost, add the location block as I mentioned above and load the forum app (which you could then store in any location really, so don't drop it in the public folder of your Refinery!) using the passenger calls there, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

probably a better approach to just host the forum at `forum.domain.com`, or you would have to set a custom route in the main application to redirect to the forum, but the forum wouldn't be able to persist the same URLs

Comment: I think this will be a better solution < you can configure virtual domain for your web server